# My android application unable to download from playstore on latest device

Tags: android, store, playback, android-app-bundle

My android application is unable to download from the playstore but even on old versions mobile can easily download my app, I have used the SDK version 28  but on the mobile device which have version 8 cant download my android app

Comment: any error while downloading??

Comment: Its showing that : cant' install, Try again and it still doesn't work

Comment: when i install it on API level 26 through playstore it easily download but on API level 28 it is unable to isntall

Comment: check targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle file

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.travelntour"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.3"
        multiDexEnabled true

Comment: Is your app compatible with your device?

Comment: when i m running by usb its running well

Comment: @PoojaKumari If same versionCode app is already installed on the device then delete it first and then download it from PlayStore

Comment: i have uninstall previous app and then installing, but unable to install

Comment: Check the android live app version on playstore. is it the latest?

Comment: now i have checked it on latest version by usb but is showing some error like : Installation failed with message failed to commit install version 1212184671 with command cmd package install-commit 1212184671. Error INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED invalid apk. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk, if it is present , and then re-installing

Comment: @PoojaKumari if you will try to install the version which is already installed on the device. Then it will give you the `Can't install` error.

Comment: @PoojaKumari your device is MI ?

Comment: Yes sir, My device is MI

Comment: May i have your MIUI version ?

Comment: Yes i have MIUI version

Comment: Mention here your Mi version pls! i have trial case not sure if it's work

Comment: i have Global 10.2

Comment: 1.Try using clear cache of your google play app from setting menu. 

2.Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options ->
Turn off "MIUI optimization" and Restart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196846/discussion-between-ajay-pandya-and-pooja-kumari).

Comment: plz help me to find solution

Comment: your device has 9 on it?  I've heard of some chinese knockoff phones lying about the version of android they have on them.

Comment: "adb logcat" log would be useful.

Comment: @PoojaKumari Let me know if you have tried both ways which i suggest as well write comment in chat discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have searched alot and check many reviews and then i found after reading the google documentation regarding this then i got this stable solution
if you have the

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:appComponentFactory=""
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name="com.travelntime.Splash">
```

then change it to

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:fullBackupContent="false">
        <activity android:name="com.travelntime.Splash">
```

and also use

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

as in case which activity you are launching

as same as:

```
<activity android:name="com.travelandtime.Splash" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

issue will resolve, if You are doing off the MIUI optimization its not a stable solution , due to this you can run on your mobile but when you upload android app on playstore then you can't install in user's mobile